# woocommerce order list action button on click

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, hook, action

I am trying to add a custom button in woocommerce order list that will send an email to the customer (the button will only show next to orders that have status 'processing' and a custom field 'deltime' is not empty). So I got the button to show but the email is send every time that I am in woocommerce/orders or during refresh instead sending only when the button is clicked. I must have understood something wrong about action hooks...any ideas?

here is the code used in functions.php :

```
// Add your custom order status action button (for orders with "processing" status)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_email_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_email_button( $actions, $order ) {
// Display the button for all orders that have a 'processing' status



    // Get Order ID (compatibility all WC versions)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    global $wpdb;
    $deltime = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = $order_id AND meta_key = 'is_gift' " );

    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) && (!empty($deltime)) ) {

    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
$mails = $mailer->get_emails();
if ( ! empty( $mails ) ) {
foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
    if ( $mail->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
       $mail->trigger( $order_id );
    }
 }
}



    // Set the action button
    $actions['partial'] = array(
        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=add_custom_email_button&order_id=' . $order_id )),
        'name'      => __( 'Αποστολή Email', 'woocommerce' ),
        'action'    => "view partial", // keep "view" class for a clean button CSS
    );
}
return $actions;
}

// Set Here the WooCommerce icon for your action button
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_email_button_css' );
function add_custom_email_button_css() {
echo '<style>.view.partial::after { font-family: woocommerce; content: "\1F4E7" !important; }</style>';
}
```

[button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ite5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it defined now, the button definition and action are in the same function, so when the button is created, its action is also performed.
You have to split the button definition and the action in two different functions:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_email_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_email_button( $actions, $order ) {
  if ( $order->status == "processing" ) {
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    global $wpdb;
    $deltime = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = $order_id AND meta_key = 'is_gift' " );

    if ( !empty( $deltime ) ) {
      // Set the action button
      $actions['partial'] = array(
        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=click_custom_email_button&order_id=' . $order_id )),
        'name'      => __( 'Αποστολή Email', 'woocommerce' ),
        'action'    => "view partial", // keep "view" class for a clean button CSS
      );
    }
  }
  return $actions;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_click_custom_email_button', 'click_custom_email_button' );
function click_custom_email_button( $order_id ) {
  $mailer = WC()->mailer();
  $mails = $mailer->get_emails();
  if ( ! empty( $mails ) ) {
    foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
      if ( $mail->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        $mail->trigger( $order_id );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately though, it didn't work. The button is not visible with the above code due to the add_action tag 'wp_ajax_click_custom_email_button' instead of the 'admin_head' I have used.

Comment: So I switched it back to the initial 'admin_head' but it still gets executed automatically when I visit the order list. Button Image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ite5V.png)

Comment: Which version of WordPress and WooCommerce are you using? The basis of how this is supposed to work is a two stage system. One function is used to display the button and define the action to be performed when the button is clicked, the second function actually executes the action. Also note that the first is a filter hook where the second is an action hook. There is no filter hook named 'admin_head'. The correct filter to add an extra action button to the order list is 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions'. Since you defined an AJAX action, the action created for you is 'wp_ajax_<action>'

Comment: I am using wordpress 4.8.3 and woocommerce 3.1.2

Comment: As for admin_head, as I understand it if I am correct, it does not require a filter hook in functions.php since it must be already included in wordpress. [admin_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head)